# MouseArea in a Disabled QML element

Tags: qml

I have a widget that is widely used in my QML Application, it's enabled property has been used in most of the places to change it's view and disable it's actions. Let's say it is something like this

```
Item {
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: doSomething();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that we need to show a message when the button is disabled, but MouseArea will also be disabled when the parent is disabled. Is there any workaround for this to force the child to remain enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the mouse area enabled property works differently from typical Items. It's really not disabled, but seems that way because the parent item is not enabled and thus cannot accept certain mouse events. To solve your problem just make the MouseArea a sibling.

Comment: My problem is that it will need numerous changes in many parts of my code, as I have used the enabled property extensively and these widgets are used everywhere! Sibling thing is not a solution unfortunately, I hope someone has a better plan! I'm totally stuck!

Comment: I'm curious about the purpose of making a button disabled but not really disabling it?  In that case just make your own "disabled" property. You could also make the MouseArea the parent item and make Item the child instead. If you're using it that much it's probably worth the time to make the button its own QML component. No matter what you're going to have to refactor.

Comment: Yes, it has its own widget. In fact many widgets are implemented with that structure. The problem is that the definition has changed. At first it was only requested that disabled widgets seem dim. It works for that, now they want to show a message when you click on a disabled button. I prefer to do this as less intrusive as possible.

Comment: Did you try setting preventStealing to true? I think that might allow mouse events even though the parent item is disabled.

Comment: Doesn't work. In fact that flag isn't even intended for that.